# print JWebBrowser content from Java Applet

Tags: java, printing, awt, html

I'm using JWebBrowser from http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/.

I've added JWebBrowser to a JFrame and I'm displaying my web page in the JWebBrowser. I tried to print the rendered content displayed in JFrame using a class that implements Printable (print utility) - using PrinterJob in the print function. I can't use javascript base print to invoke the native browser print dialog since i need to change page settings (header, footer etc) before printing.

When i print the Jframe to the printer, I can't see the contents of JWebBrowser. I tested the same print utility using JEditorPane (not as good as JWebBrowser in rendering web pages) and it printed the content.

Anyone has any idea on how to print the content of JWebBrowser using PrinterJob?

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Just trying to get help here. You were right, it's urgent for our client and my company and I don't have to mention about that in my question (removed it now). We got about a week to finish this, but we need to implement few other functionalities on top of this printing functionality, so that's why I mentioned its urgent. Didn't mean to offend or frustrate anyone. Please let me know if you have any possible solution.

Comment: Good edit.  Now I actually read the text carefully, what does this have to do with applets?  While 'applet' can mean 'small application' it is more commonly used to refer to a `java.applet.Applet` or `javax.swing.JApplet`.  It seems this app. is based around a `JFrame`.  Also why are you trying to print the frame rather than calling [`JWebBrowser.print(true)`](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/components/JWebBrowser.html#print%28boolean%29)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm using JFrame in my test application so that I can see the rendered content before printing. The final production code will be a JApplet whose job is to print the rendered content of the page (ASP.Net) where the JApplet is loaded from. I need to set some page settings like header, footer, margin and page orientation before printing, so I need to use PrinterJob to set these settings and can't use JWebBrowser.print(true). All I need to do is to load a page and print its rendered content with custom page settings.

Comment: OK - beyond 'remove the applet tag' (which might cause a people to ignore the post), and add AWT, I'm out of ideas.  `JWebBrowser` is a Swing based class so the problem is not 'mixing Swing & AWT components'.